# "Compute" a distribution

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

I have the task to comupute the following expression:

\begin{align}
\exp(-\vert x\vert^2) \partial^2_{x_1 x_2}\mathbb{1}_{x_1>0,x_2>0} \in \mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^2).
\end{align}

Anyone an idea what to do? I really do not understand what to compute... I mean a distribution is a function...?! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

A distribution is a linear functional on the space $\mathcal{D}(\Bbb R^2)$ of $C^\infty$ function with compact support. Let $\phi\in\mathcal{D}(\Bbb R^2)$. Then
$$\begin{align}
\big\langle e^{-|x|^2}\partial_{x_1,x_2}\Bbb 1_{x_1>0,x_2>0},\phi\bigr\rangle&=
\big\langle \partial_{x_1,x_2}\Bbb 1_{x_1>0,x_2>0},e^{-|x|^2}\phi\bigr\rangle\\
&=\big\langle \Bbb 1_{x_1>0,x_2>0},\partial_{x_1,x_2}\bigl(e^{-|x|^2}\phi\bigr)\bigr\rangle\\
&=\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty\partial_{x_1,x_2}\bigl(e^{-|x|^2}\phi\bigr)\,dx_1dx_2\\
&=\phi(0,0).
\end{align}$$
That is,
$$
e^{-|x|^2}\partial_{x_1,x_2}\Bbb 1_{x_1>0,x_2>0}=\delta_{(0,0)}.
$$

Comment: Could you please explain to me the first and the second "$=$"

Comment: They are the definition of the product of a function and a distribution and of the derivative of a distribution.

Comment: could you please write them down?

Comment: btw. I am not familiar with this notion with the inner product...

Comment: It is not an inner product. $\langle T,\phi\rangle$ is notation for the action of the distribution $T$ on the function $\phi$. The notation $T(\phi)$ is also used.

Comment: and in your notation, how would I write $T_f(\phi)$?

Comment: $\langle T_f,\phi\rangle$.